# VB Compiler Error(No Clue)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Okay i keep getting this error and i have done all there is to do but it just wouldn't go. Can anyone give me any idea please?

```
Project-level conditional compilation constant 'VBC_VER = 9.0, TARGET = "winexe", CONFIG= "Debug", PLATFORM= "x86" , DEBUG; ^^ ^^ TRACE' is not valid: Character is not valid
```

Comment: Wild guess: put 9.0 in quotes?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. But after I used `,` as the seperating character between constatnts instead of `;`, it works. So have a try with `,` only.

Comment: Really strange that this would be true but the delimiter in a csproj is semicolon while its a comma in vbproj

Answer (score 0):

You have set a conditional compilation constant that contains an invalid character. Check your project properties.

Comment: I don't seem to see anything on there.Am so clueless on this particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would say one of those conditions has a syntax error. though I don't know which. Could it be win.exe instead of winexe?

Comment: Should i change it to win.exe? Sorry am pretty new at this so i don't know much about properties.

Comment: I don't know what's going wrong other than it's a syntax error. so I'd try it out and anything else you think of?

It may be worth creating a new project and copying all your code into it if you can't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Project, YourProjectProperties, Compile, Advanced Compile Options, remove the `DEBUG:TRACE` in the "`Custom constants:`" and check the Define `DEBUG` constant and Define `TRACE` constant, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

This might not apply to your problem, but everyone runs into this sooner or later:

If you copied the VBS script from a web page or MS-Word document, the leading and/or trailing quotes (both single quote (') and double quote (") probably aren't what they seem... They can actually be forward and reverse quotes, which are entirely different characters than what VBS is expecting (look carefully - You can actually tell the difference because the quotes will be tilted left or right, but it isn't obvious).

These oddball right/left quote characters will survive a conversion from Unicode to ANSI, and will cause VBS Invalid Character or Unterminated String errors every time.

In Notepad, try searching for " and ' in separate searches. If you notice Search skipping any quote characters that it should find, there's your problem. Copy/Paste that sucker into Notepad's REPLACE FROM box, and type the normal quote character that VBS is expecting into the TO box, and do a mass-replace on all of them. Then be sure to do a Save As, and choose ANSI in Windows 7 Notepad and above. Windows XP users might need Notepad++ (a free download) to save as ANSI.

Even better, you can avoid searching for skipped quotes by just typing the single and double reverse and forward quotes directly into the Replace From box, but i forgot the Ctrl or Alt keyboard sequence to do that. Bear in mind, if you look at Windows Character Map, you'll see LOTS of oddball forward and reverse quotes, even reverse commas, all with different character codes - but Word and certain web page editors have their favorite beautification characters, unless the script you copied is formatted as Source Code, or written in a TextArea box like StackOverflow usually lists source code.

Other weird characters can cause problems when copy/pasting from web pages or Word documents, but I forgot what they are.